# Sugya summary for each mesechta

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation

I am looking for an English sefer that contains a summary of each sugya in a mesechta as well as the halachos learned in that sugya.

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: this is something, not sure what exactly: take a look https://www.amazon.com/Daf-BIyun-Berachos-Concise-develop/dp/1533299102